# Setting constructors in the main class instead of sub-classes

Tags: java, class, constructor, get, set

in my code I have a a main class and a couple of sub classes:

```
public abstract class Items {
    public int itemId;

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public Items(int itemID) {
        setItemId(itemID);
    }
}

 abstract class Equipment extends Items {
    public double attackBonus;
    public double defenceBonus;
    public double speedBonus;

    public String equipItem() {
    return itemName + " has been equiped";
    }
}

class Gathering extends Items {
}

class Creation extends Items {

}
```

I got my constructor in the main class but it doesn't work, but if I placed them into the Gathering and Creation class. Only problem is this is causing me repetitive code which is why I want it in the main class but this is causing me errors.

the error is:
Implicit super constructor Items() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Comment: It's asking me to add a constructor to all my sub-classes

Comment: Added the whole code now

Comment: Then Reimeus is correct, since you cannot use a default constructor, your subclasses *must* have constructors of their own, written along the lines of what Reimeus has written. The key is that all instances of Items needs to have an itemID passed into it. 1+ for the edit, and thanks for editing your question.

Comment: So really I can't avoid having to reduplicate the code in all my sub-classes?

Comment: The problem is that I have all together, 7-8 classes which needs an ID, so that would mean I'd have to create a constructor in all my classes which seems very repetitive

Comment: Synthnet: `so that would mean I'd have to create a constructor in all my classes`: yes, constructors can't be inherited. `which seems very repetitive`: yes, but you've little choice, if the non-default constructor is required for the parent class.

Comment: Damn, that's pretty lame but I guess if I have to, I have to, cheers Hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear but constructors need to be explicitly implemented the super-class contains a constructor that takes one or more arguments:

```
class Gathering extends Items {

    public Gathering(int itemID) {
        super(itemID);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid, I cna get it working doing this but I don't want to have to add it to my sub-classes because it's causing repetitive code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have no "default constructor", which in Java means a constructor with no arguments, in your superclass, your subclasses cannot use the default constructor that would be provided by default when you don't specify a constructor.

Think of how many possible values there are for an integer. Sure, it could call super (0), but that's hard to know that it is happening. And what if you wanted your subclasses to default to 3? So Java is made to not bother with this - you must make your own constructor in subclasses if you don't have a default in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can see to avoid repeating the constructor.
The easiest would be to use the default constructor, and then your setter:

```
Gathering g = new Gathering();
g.setItemId(6);
```

You can make that into one line with some method chaining: in `Items`, add

```
public Items setTItemId(int itemId) {
    setItemId(itemId);
    return this;
}
```

and then you can call

```
Creation c = (Creation) ( (new Creation()) .setTItemId(7) );
```

But I don't know how readable that last line is.

**Edit:**

A third way uses generics, but you have to delete `Equipment`.  Start with

```
abstract class Item<T extends Item>
```

with the same chaining setter

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T setTItemId(int itemId) {
    setItemId(itemId);
    return (T)this;
}
```

Then

```
class Creation extends Item<Creation> {}
```

lets you call

```
Creation c = (new Creation()) .setTItemId(7);
```